# Given a number, print out its "collective sum"

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Given a number as input, print out its **collective sum**

What is a collective sum?

Consider the number `13214`, the input

Looping through each of the digits starting from the left, we will be able to obtain its collective sum.

`1` means look at the first digit, and add it to the sum, sum = 1

`3` means look at the "first 3 digits" and add it to the sum, sum = 1 + 132

`2` means look at the "first 2 digits" and add it to the sum, sum = 1 + 132 + 13

`1` means look at the first digit, and add it to the sum, sum = 1 + 132 + 13 + 1

`4` means look at the "first 4 digits" and add it to the sum, sum = 1 + 132 + 13 + 1 + 1321

Total sum = `1468` and this is your output

---

> Special cases:

If we encounter a `0`, then clearly we keep the sum the same

```
The number 1301 would have a sum = 1 + 130 + 1 = 132
```

If we encounter a number that is larger then the length of the input, we add it all

```
The number 251 would have a sum = 25 + 251 + 2 = 278
```

---

> Test cases:

```
collectiveSum(0) = 0

collectiveSum(2) = 2

collectiveSum(2315) = 23 + 231 + 2 + 2315 = 2571
```

---

Shortest amount of bytes wins. Happy golfing!

Comment: As is often a question with these kinds of tasks: May we accept a list of the digits as our input?

Comment: The `2315` test case is missing the `+ 2` from the `1` and should result in `2571`.

Comment: Do we expect to have to deal with inputs starting with 0 aside from 0? How should the program deal with these inputs

Comment: It looks like the last test case is wrong; should be `2571`.

Comment: I don't see why the input should be a number rather than a list of integers.  It seems like an unnecessarily cumbersome form of input.

Comment: I'm not sure what kinds of inputs are allowed, can I take a list of integers as input?

Comment: I'd recommend against accepting answers at all (see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8363/66833)), but if you do want to have an accepted answer, I'd wait about a week, so that the competition still seems open.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>4</s>  3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

-1 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen (use of `€` avoiding a `}`)

```
€£O
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UdOaQ4v9//83MjY0BQA)**

#### How?

```
€£O - implicit input   e.g. 2315
€   - map with:
 £  -   head to             23, 231, 2, 2315
  O - sum                   2571
```

Comment: Beat me by 13 seconds xD

Comment: Glad I waited to add the link to bytes then :p

Comment: `ε£}` can be `€£` to save a byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen was that also an option when I created this?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Not entirely sure, but I think it indeed already was. _Adnan_ started writing the Elixir rewrite in the Summer of 2018 (which was released in August), and `€` was already there for quite a while in the legacy version of 05AB1E before that. It was already there when I posted my very first 05AB1E answer in April 2018. So it might be possible it was added shortly after you posted this answer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it looks like it did. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(int('0'+n[:int(x)])for x in n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyMzr0RD3UBdOy/aCsSs0IzVTMsvUqhQyMxTyNP8X1AEFFVI0yhKLI/PzCsoLdHQ1PxvaGxgCAA)

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to raise a `ValueError` for input of `1301`, or any input that has a zero as one of its digits.

Comment: @mathmandan Should be fixed now?

Comment: The `int` function can accept an integer, replacing the `'0'` string literal with just `0` should shave off one byte.

Comment: @MooseOnTheRocks Did in a way that seems less hacky-looking (?) to me, unless I'm stupid and messed something up (usually)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 72 bytes

First submission! Thanks to @DestructibleLemon for the help!

```
import sys;d=sys.argv[1];s=0;for e in d:s+=int(d[:int(e)]);print str(s)
```

Comment: Just so you know, the downvote seems to have been given automatically by the [community user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) when I edited the header of your post. Sorry. It's an [annoying, nonsensical feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276269/community-should-not-autodownvote-low-quality-autoflags-cleared-by-edits). Though I don't know why it did that this time, because as far as I can tell, this was *not* flagged as low-quality.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first submission! And yeah, as Steadybox said, the downvote was automatically placed for no good reason in particular. Your post has gotten a few upvotes so hopefully at the next cron job the automatic downvote should be removed :)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>43</s> 37 bytes

```
f l=sum[read$'0':take(read[d])l|d<-l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hx7a4NDe6KDUxRUXdQN2qJDE7VQPEi06J1cypSbHRzYn9n5uYmadgq5CbWOAbr6BRUJSZV6KXpqkQzaWgoGRobGRooqQDYhpAKCMoZWxoqhT7HwA)

The input number is taken as a string.

```
   [        |d<-l]      -- for every digit d in the input string
        read[d]         -- convert to a number
      take     l        -- and take that many digits from l
     0:                 -- prepend a 0 (to handle 0s)
   read                 -- convert to a number
sum                     -- sum all numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.sum{|x|n[0,x.to_i].join.to_i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@vuDS3uqaiJi/aQKdCryQ/PjNWLys/Mw/MrK39X6CQFp2eWlKsl5yRWFQc@9/Q2MjQBAA)

Comment: `#sum` isn't defined on fixnums, so I assume you want `n` to be a string. However, `String#sum` computes a `not a particularly good checksum` and ignores the block you give it. If you meant `n.chars.sum{`, `Enumerable#sum` isn't in the ruby stdlib, it's an extension provided by rails. Please test your solutions before posting them.

Comment: @Shelvacu Yeah, I'm taking input as an array though... see the footer provided. Plus [`Enumerable#sum` is in Ruby 2.4](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/02/ruby-2-4-introduces-enumerable-sum.html), and [TIO uses 2.4](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhKNQpMj7MNSjY09/v/38A)

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@vuDS3uqaiJk8vKz8zL9pApyJWryQ/PrO29n@BQlp0empJsV5yRmJRsV5uYoGCmhVILva/obGRoQkA) if you take an array of digits as input

Comment: @AsoneTuhid I don't think that's a valid form of input, if you find evidence otherwise please explain

Comment: [This page](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) doesn't seem to address the issue but i don't see a list of integers as being too different from a list of characters (which is what your answer takes as input)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

Thanks @Shaggy for golfing off 2 bytes

```js
f=
x=>[...x].map(y=>a+=+x.slice(0,y),a=0)|a

console.log(f("2315"))
console.log(f("0100"))
console.log(f("2"))
console.log(f("01025"))
```

Receives input as a string and returns an integer. As currently written, this code leaves leading zeroes on any integers.

Comment: 40 bytes: `x=>[...x].map(y=>a+=+x.slice(0,y),a=0)|a`

Answer (score 3):

## R, 57 bytes

saved one more thanks to @Vlo

```
sum(strtoi(substring(i<-scan(,""),1,el(strsplit(i,"")))))
```

was:
Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Robert Hacken's suggestion.

```
i=scan(,"");sum(strtoi(substring(i,1,el(strsplit(i,"")))))
```

A simple string approach.

Comment: You can save 4 bytes replacing `unlist` by `el`.

Comment: Save 1 with inline assignment `sum(strtoi(substring(i<-scan(,""),1,el(strsplit(i,"")))))`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 106 bytes

```c
j,k,c,t;f(char*S){for(t=j=0;S[j];j++)c=S[k=S[j]-48<(c=strlen(S))?S[j]-48:c],S[k]=0,t+=atoi(S),S[k]=c;S=t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NCsIwEIRfpQQKuzaF@gdiXKTPkGPNoaxGk2oqaW7FZ68tepxvvmG4vDNPk5edZJmUBX60caVxtH2ERJ4qpRtvlC8KZNJNR0ssd4cTMA0pPm8BNOL5T49s5CwZqmQqqE29m9sfYaUpqc/0al0AHJefrG4Mic12vRfqHV1IFoSFfMCMsvx6CULW0kKNOM@@)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 thanks to Dennis (head vectorises >.<)

<sup>4 if we may take lists of digits*</sup>

```
Dḣ`ḌS
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4Y7FCQ939AT////fyNjQFAA)**

* `` ḣ`ḌS ``

#### How?

```
Dḣ`ḌS - Link: integer, n   e.g. 2315
D     - to decimal list         [2,3,1,5]
  `   - repeat left as right    [2,3,1,5]
 ḣ    - head                    [2,3], [2,3,1], [2], [2,3,1,5]
   Ḍ  - from decimal lists      23, 231, 2, 2315
    S - sum                     2571
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩΣＩＥθ✂θ⁰Ｉι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0F8LwTSzQKNRRCM7JTE4FMQx0FMDimZoQYP3/v5Gxoel/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｅθ       Map over input string
        Ｉι  Cast current character to integer
     ✂θ⁰    Slice input string to that length
 ΣＩ         Cast slices to integer and take the sum
Ｉ           Cast result to string and implicitly print
```

Comment: Haha, I had the exact same thing

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 56 bytes

```matlab
@(n)sum(str2num(['' 32+char(n.*(find(n)<=(n'-48))-32)]))
```

Anonymous function that takes a string as input argument and returns a number as output.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##LcpBDkAwEIXhvVPYzQzR6JTEgsQ9xELQsDASxfVL6Or/XvL28Rzu2dtGKeVbFHLXhu48WN52ALHhdFyGA0UlaFeZ3kvdoEBWVESZYeqJvEXQhnUBFH3M9S8uA/KwQ4wugfwD)

The shorter version

```matlab
@(n)sum(str2num(['' char(n.*(find(n)<=(n'-48)))]))
```

works in Matlab, because `char(0)` is treated as a space.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 27 bytes

```perl6
{sum $_ X[&substr]^«.comb}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##RZDRaoMwGIXv8xQHJkWpFZNWWyqWPcQuBmMbrc2GTKuYWFZKn2hvsRdz/x9lvTlJvnP4k5NWd1U69EbjnEZFJkR9waxojhr5cDV9De8dzy8z0x@M7V7ffn@ioqkPt4Fij1Ybixy@AORSyRXyHeQq3YR4gMScoVOW8SgpSmssOcrgHo1Z2YZKRlut3SSVkMOM1PlA7HxayZ@QmpCb6HJqKROGKllLB/kdBFnHXSICKszdn6hJJtpqf8Lc1crER9NNDRc7/gQf2y998b3y1PY2CLE976te@57@bnVh9TFAgCvdWxrw992D/4kQ0WdprLgNfw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit param ｢$_｣

  sum

    $_           # the input

      X[&substr] # crossed using &substr sub as if it was an infix operator

    ^«\          # upto ｢^｣ for each of the following ｢«｣ (creates Range objects)
    .comb        # the input split into digits (implicit method call on ｢$_｣
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>77</s> 75 bytes

Has to be compiled with the `-lm` switch or GCC doesn't recognize the math functions.

```c
r,q,i;f(n){for(r=0,i=n;i;i/=10)q=log10(n)+1-i%10,r+=n/pow(10,q>0?q:0);n=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc3RCoMgFAbg6/kUEgRKRlrrZmJ7kd2EoQh1Sje2i@jV53JrV/8H/885urRaxxiYZ04aAnQ1cyBBceYUSCddpQSnXo2zFXyvC1G6XHAWCgXVMr/Ibt/xq79wKkEFucXn7AZsiYMHBopWdFrCbkOyfMCqw/lwg4xhYDi9oxJtCKXt1Dsg370l@60U9RGNaH8STS3Of3Jx1G3CFt/ajL29x3KcPg)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 55 bytes

```
[0*]sq?dsfZ1-se[lfddZrIle^/I%-d0>qIr^/+led1-se0<a]dsaxp
```

No strings nor arrays! Indeed, the required digits are acquired solely through mathematical manipulation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z/aQCu2uNA@pTgtylC3ODU6Jy0lJarIMyc1Tt9TVTfFwK7QsyhOXzsnNQUkbWCTGJtSnFhR8P@/obGRoQkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
ṁd´M↑d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxpRDW3wftU1M@f//v5GxoSkA)

#### Explanation

```
ṁd´M↑d  -- example input: 1301
     d  -- decimal digits: [1,3,0,1]
  ´M    -- map over it using it as argument (example with 3):
    ↑   -- | take: [1,3,0]
        -- : [[1],[1,3,0],[],[1]]
ṁ       -- map and then sum the result (example on [1,3,0]):
 d      -- | as decimal: 130
        -- : 1 + 130 + 0 + 1 = 132
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 5 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```
¬x@¯X
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rHhAr1g=&input=IjEzMjE0Ig==)

---

### Explanation

```
          :Implicit input of integer string U
¬         :Split to an array of characters/digits
  @       :Pass each X through a function
   ¯X     :Slice U from the first to the Xth character
 x        :Reduce by addition
```

Comment: O_o Either Japt is really golfy or I'm doing Actually wrong

Comment: @ASCII-only: Japt is a lot more "golfy" than most people realise; we win our fair share of challenges, even beating Charcoal *and* SOGL in a recent [tag:ascii-art] challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy Sure, but I didn't realize it was Jelly/Actually/05AB1E level golfy

Comment: @ASCII-only: Oh, yeah, it's definitely up there with them, holding it's own nicely :) If you're interested, have a look at our language of the month nom. or drop into the Japt chatroom sometime and we'll give you a tour.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
[:+/"."0".@{."0 1]
```

### Explanation

Takes a string as input

```
           {."0 1  - take
    "."0           - current char as int items
                 ] - from the argument
         ".        - and convert them to an integer  
[:+/               - add them up
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o6209ZX0lAyU9ByqgZSCYex/TS4FrtTkjHyFNAV1Q2MjQxN1JK6BIYJnZIrEMUASR2IaG5qqc/0HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç╫&º±å
```

[Run and debug it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A7%E2%95%AB%26%C2%BA%C2%B1%C3%A5&i=13214%0A1301%0A251%0A2%0A0%0A2315&a=1&m=2)

The corresponding ascii representation of the same program is this.

```
EZFy(e+

E        get array of digits
 Z       push 0 under array of digits
  F      for each digit, run the rest of the program
   y     input as a string
    (    get start of string for specified number of characters
     e   evaluate substring as integer
      +  add
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

```
╝ß⌠≈╛H≈⌡MΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///R1LmH5z/qWfCos@PR1NkeIKpnoe@5xf//KxkaGxmaKAEA)

## Explanation

```
╝          Push input to register 1
 ß         Push n-th input (0 by default)
        M  Map
  ⌠    ⌡   Function
   ≈       Cast current character of input to int
    ╛      Get value of register 1 (input)
     H     Push input[:current character]
      ≈    Cast to int
         Σ Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 43 bytes

It's well after 3 in the morning, why am I still golfing?!

Takes input as a string.

```
s=>(g=x=>s[x]?+s.slice(0,s[x])+g(++x):0)(0)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bco9CoQwEEDh3mNYzRCViT@NED2IbCExBiUYcZYlt49ubcr38fb5N7O@tvNbHn4xcVWR1QBWBTXwFD6j4Irdpg1Q8W8UFoQI2BMCYdT@YO9M5byFFXLZ1LLNEbOXk0xw3aWUUmfKGtk9HG8)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 26 bytes

Includes `+1` for `p`

```
perl -pE 's%.%/.{0,$&}/;$\+=$&%eg}{' <<< 2315; echo
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 22 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/10/:'(x&#x)#\:x:10\:
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k)+/10/:'(x&#x)#\:x:10\:13214
1468
q)k)+/10/:'(x&#x)#\:x:10\:1301
132
q)k)+/10/:'(x&#x)#\:x:10\:251
278
q)k)+/10/:'(x&#x)#\:x:10\:2315
2571
```

**Explanation:**

Break into base-10, take min of each number and the length of list from this. Convert back and sum up.

```
+/10/:'(x&#x)#\:x:10\: / the solution
                  10\: / to base 10, 123 => 1 2 3
                x:     / save as x
             #\:       / take (#) each left
       (    )          / the left
          #x           / count (#) length of x
        x&             / min of x and the length
  10/:'                / from base 10 each
+/                     / sum up the results
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 92 bytes

```java
n->n.chars().map(c->(c-=48)>0?new Integer(n.substring(0,c<n.length()?c:n.length())):0).sum()
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY8/b8JADMV3PoXFdJaaUwJUqvgTZgZYGKsO5jjCQeJEuQsIVfnsqRsidaqQ7MHPP/k9X@hGUVlZvhyvncnJe9iS4@8RgONg6xMZC7vfsRfAqH2oHWfAuBCxlZbygYIzsAOGFXQcpazNmWqvUBdUKROl0qvZB6bxmu0dNnI6s7Vi7ZuD7w@q@M0sWeeWs3BWuDbzvwFxHqOghcJu8XSsmkMujoPxrXRHKCT3kO7zi/CZef/wwRa6bIKuZBNyFlOjxvEY@wf@JyaviWny/hJKppNkNlDtqO1@AA)

```java
n->                                  // Method with String parameter and int return-type
  n.chars()                          //  Loop over the characters
   .map(c->(c-=48)                   //   Convert character to digit
        >0?                          //    And if it's larger than 0
         new Integer(n.substring(0,  //     Take the first `x` digits, where `x` is:
          c<n.length()?              //      If the digit higher than the total a.o. digits
           c                         //       Take the first `c` digits
          :                          //      Else:
           n.length()))              //       Take all digits
         :                           //    Else:
          0)                         //     Take 0
   .sum()                            //   And sum everything
```

Answer (score 0):

**REXX 118 bytes**

```
pull n                           
l=length(n)                      
a=0                              
j=1                              
do while (j<=l)                  
if substr(n,j,1)==0 then m=0;    
else m=substr(n,1,substr(n,j,1));
a=a+m                            
j=j+1                            
end                              
say a
```

[Try it here](http://tpcg.io/Qm71Pi)
Provide Input value in the STDIN tab.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum([int(str(n)[:int(i)])if i!='0'else 0for i in str(n)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxCoAgEIDhvae4Jr1Ns5agJ6kGo6SDukJt6OmNiMDt@@E/77gebJLrhrTZfZotcBuuXfbEUYboJWPfviYckRxQ2Qklli0soNzhgYAYvm/EdPp3dVKbSteIxd8qc5Xb6AYxPQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
DµḣµVS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l0NaHOxYf2hoW/P//f0NjI0MTAA)

Get the `D`igits of the input, then get the first [each digit] elements of the input (`ḣ`ead), then e`V`al each sum to make it a number again and `S`um.